# Terraform , need help to import existing ressource to a module ressource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I would like to import an existing resource into my module.

This is my "old" vpc file: https://pastebin.com/DVsacfwt
My new one using the terraform registry vpc module: https://pastebin.com/KDrA0Db3

I'm in my directory, I copy my file where I use the module, I execute terraform plan and Terraform tell me that it need to create 10 new ressources https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxnJm.jpg which is NORMAL because I didn't migrate my vpc into my module.

Then I run terraform state mv aws_vpc.vpc-demosubs module.vpc-demosubs.aws_vpc.this https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4dZT.jpg

When I execute terraform plan again, Terraform need to create and destroy new resources...https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpWU2.jpg

Do you have an idea?

Comment: You need to attach full plan output, not a screenshot of it's part.